# full outer join with group by query

Tags: sql, oracle

Calculate profit of company by month, profit of company calculated like this:
`sum of incoming minus outgoing`.

Tables:

1. incoming(amount, month)
2. outgoing(amount, month)

Data types:

- month integer, ranges 1-12
- amount integer

I tried

```
SELECT month,tsum-bsum FROM
(SELECT month,SUM(amount) tsum FROM incoming GROUP BY month
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT month,SUM(amount) bsum FROM outgoing GROUP BY month)
)
ON incoming.month=outgoing.month;
```

but month can be null after joining which will cause problem with tsum-bsum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(i.month, o.month) as month, i.tsum - o.bsum
FROM (SELECT month, SUM(amount) as tsum FROM incoming GROUP BY month) i
     FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT month, SUM(amount) as bsum FROM outgoing GROUP BY month) o
     ON i.month = o.month;
```

Note that the difference may be `NULL` if either value is `NULL`, so you may want:

```
SELECT coalesce(i.month, o.month) as month,
       coalesce(i.tsum, 0) - coalesce(o.bsum, 0) as diff
FROM (SELECT month, SUM(amount) as tsum FROM incoming GROUP BY month) i
     FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT month, SUM(amount) as bsum FROM outgoing GROUP BY month) o
     ON i.month = o.month;
```

Answer (score 0):

here is sample query

```
SELECT COALESCE(in.month, out.month) as month, sum(COALESCE(in.amount,0) - COALESCE(out.amount,0)) as profit
FROM
    incoming as in
FULL OUTER JOIN
    outgoing as out
ON in.month = out.month;
GROUP BY COALESCE(in.month, out.month)
```